# Add Framework to Module in IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create an IntelliJ Plugin to automatically create a project type. I've gotten as far as making a custom ModuleBuilder with an area for inserting a Group ID and Artifact ID.

When the project is created, I want it to immediately come with gradle support, as well as a filled out build.gradle file and other stuff.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

```
class SpigotKtWizard : ModuleBuilder() {

override fun setupRootModel(modifiableRootModel: ModifiableRootModel?) {}

override fun getModuleType(): ModuleType<*> {
    return SpigotKtModuleType.instance
}

override fun createWizardSteps(wizardContext: WizardContext, modulesProvider: ModulesProvider): Array<ModuleWizardStep> {
    return arrayOf(BuildOptionsStep())
}

override fun createProject(name: String?, path: String?): Project? {
    val project = super.createProject(name, path) ?: return null
    setupModule()
    val d = project.baseDir.createChildData(this, "Test")
    File(d.path).writeText("Testing boyyyy")
    return project
}}
```

What I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a Gradle project, it's much better to use a different API - [`GradleFrameworkSupportProvider`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/idea-gradle/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/configuration/GradleKotlinFrameworkSupportProvider.kt). Then the user will choose Gradle in the new project wizard, and your framework in the list of frameworks to add. As an example, you can refer to the implementation in the [Kotlin plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/idea-gradle/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/configuration/GradleKotlinFrameworkSupportProvider.kt).

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to implement this (i've been at it for a few hours). I'm entirely new to IntelliJ plugins, just started last night, so maybe that's why. How would I go about implementing this?